# How to use JavaScript in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to know how can I use JavaScript in Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

When I tried to write JavaScript in Microsoft Visual Studio Code, I received no error and also no result of my code, so I need to know how to make the code work.

I used too many extensions for the vs Code, but I still can't get the result.

I am expecting that the code works directly without problems and to work on the VS code direct without opening a web page...

Answer (score 1):

Goto extentions install the ones related to JS such as live server etc.  And start coding. I think you will have to use browser to try your code.